# VS 2005 to VS 2012: do I need a cast now?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005, typedef

OK, I have been searching for a solution to my error all day, so this is kind of my last hope.

I have ported this solution from VS 2005 to VS 2012 so that may make a difference if some settings or the compiler have changed.

I have a typedef which is then used in a struct in a template:

```
typedef bool (__cdecl *tBreakPointer)(const double&, const double&);

template <typename _T>
struct s_OptParameter
{
  tBreakPointer pAbortPointer;
};
```

These are the lines that give me the error (line in switch statement with '=' in it):

```
OptPara.nID = static_cast<unsigned int>(m_ParameterList->IndexOf(Item));
OptPara.nScale = Item->Scale;

switch (Item->Abort)
{
  case GeneticAbortType::Greater:
    OptPara.pAbortPointer = checkGreater;
    break;
}
```

checkGreater is defined as this:

```
bool checkGreater(const double& nAct, const double& nBreak)
{
  return (nAct > nBreak);
}
```

Now this is the error I get:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'bool (__stdcall *)(const double &,const double &)' to 'tBreakPointer'
This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
```

All the usual answers don't seem to fit my problem as my code has been fine in VS 2005 and is not in VS 2012 - so any help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried either changing checkGreater's calling convention to __cdecl or changing the tBreakPointer typedef to __stdcall?

Comment: I have tried neither - will do so.

Comment: You have a mismatch in the calling convention, __cdecl vs __stdcall.  That is a nasty mismatch and one you should never ignore.  Casting away the error just causes drastic misbehavior at runtime when the stack gets imbalanced.  It is otherwise very unclear how checkGreater() ended up as __stdcall, you didn't declare it that way.  Which makes it likely that you have a compile setting wrong.   Project + Properties, C/C++, Advanced, Calling Convention.

Comment: Hans Passant, you are right. Somehow one of my projects was set to __stdcall. Thank you very much! Should I rephrase this as an answer now or can your comment be converted to an answer?